# Find date/time for mysql "SELECT MIN(Celsius)"

Tags: mysql

Using this:

`$maxtime = mysql_query(  //Outdoortemp max
    "SELECT MIN(Celsius), time
    FROM`digitemp
    `WHERE`SerialNumber`LIKE '105C0EE5000800B4'
    AND time LIKE '$datetime'
    ORDER BY time");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($maxtime);
    echo $row['time'];
    echo '----';
    echo $row['MIN(Celsius)'];`

gives me "2015-11-23 00:00:09-----8.31" but the minimum temp occurred around 8 AM. How do I do for getting the date/time from the actual line containing the minimum temperature? The $datetime is the time getting from the form choosing date (calendar style).
Thanks, Ralph in Sweden

Comment: Why 'like' ????? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: It's not so easy because the actual result comes as a diagram: Link: http://tempuss.dyndns.info/index.php

Comment: I am using temperature measuring with "digitemp" software that every four minutes records dtKey, time, SerialNumber and Celsius into a row in mysql. Making my question more general: How do I in a mysql query get a minimum reading and from the same line the time from the column in that line.

Comment: It's not so easy? You have a table with three columns and some data. What's hard about replicating that?

Comment: I wonder too. I'm fetching the array and got the correct temperature reading but not the date/time as seen above. If you know how, why don't you tell me??

Comment: So the "SELECT MIN(Celsius)" gives only the minimum temperature for that day and not all the data where it is. I don't understand that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a three-step process in SQL.

First, you need to find the temperature extremes. That you do like so.

```
        SELECT MIN(Celsius) Mintemp,
               SerialNumber,
               DATE(`time`) Daystamp
          FROM digitemp
         GROUP BY SerialNumber, DATE(`time`)
```

This gives you a list of dates, sensors, and minimum times.

Then you join that resultset to your main table to extract the detail rows matching the minimum temperature.

```
 SELECT a.`time`, a.Celsius, a.SerialNumber
   FROM digitemp a
   JOIN (
            SELECT MIN(Celsius) Mintemp,
                   SerialNumber,
                   DATE(`time`) Daystamp
              FROM digitemp
         GROUP BY SerialNumber, DATE(`time`)
        ) b     ON a.Celsius = b.MinTemp
               AND a.SerialNumber = b.SerialNumber
               AND DATE(a.`time`) = b.Daystamp
```

See how the ON clause of the JOIN matches up the rows in your `digitemp` detail record to the rows in the minimum query?

Finally, if you want just a particular range of dates, or a particular sensor, you append a suitable WHERE clause. For example this gives yesterday's readings.

```
   WHERE a.`time` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
     AND a.`time < CURDATE()
     AND a.SerialNumber = '105C0EE5000800B4'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ollie. I thought it was simpler than that but I understand that the date doesn't correspond to the line with the minimum temp as I extract it. It works ok to just getting the minimum. I will try your excellent tip.